# CSS image not showing in Sublime Text 2

Tags: html, css

I recently purchased a licence for the program, however anytime I put in a background image into the CSS (also the same with SASS), nothing seems to work.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Does Sublime Text 2 CSS Work?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: It's probably nothing to do with Sublime text - what doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your path to your image should be:

```
background-image : url('../img/background.jpg');
```

This is why your image doesn't show up, you need to get to the root of your folder then enter the "img" folder to get to the image.

Also, if your folder is made like this:

- MAINFOLDER:

index.html

- css:

stylesheet.css

- img:

background.jpg

your path to your stylesheet should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the image is not in the right relative path to the style sheet. If your CSS file is in a folder off your web root such as http://example.com/css/site.css, then the browser is going to look for the background image at http://example.com/css/bg-img.jpg ... which would be a pretty odd place to put it.

Try putting the full path to the file in your css...something like this:

```
body{
background-image: url('/background.jpg');
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

(And make sure thatbackground.jpg actually lives in /images/, of course!)

Comment: I would just add that the culprit here is most likely not Sublime Text, but rather the code itself.